# Facebook Graph API Search Posts for specific text in message field

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a way with graph facebook to search specific text content in the message of a user's posts?  The assumption here is that the user id and access token is already available as well as all applicable permissions (ie. the user_posts permissions, etc..).

I read through the search feature on graph:

[Facebook Graph Docs-Advanced](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced)

The following graph explorer example was provided:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/search?
    q={your-query}&
    type={object-type}
```

The table that lists the available types in the link provided is very limited (place, placetopic, ad_*).  Is that the full list of possible types?  Can we use POSTS or user posts as a type.  I couldn't find the right syntax anywhere.

My goal is to retrieve a user's posts based on a specific message tag or text in their post message.  Currently, the only way I know how to do this is highly inefficient.  I would have to do the following:

1. Get user's full list of posts

https://graph/facebook/com/{version}/{userID}/?fields=posts&access_token={token}

2. Run a coded query to get the posts I need and discard the rest

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to search through user posts like that. Your current “highly inefficient way”, is also the _only_ one. _“My goal is to retrieve a user's posts based on a specific message tag or text in their post message.”_ - and the _actual_ goal behind that goal would be what? What do you intend to do with those posts, once you found them?

Comment: I want my app to basically authenticate a user, ask for post permissions and store specific posts pertaining to content that the user creates on behalf of a client.  I didn't want to store all user posts and just focus on the content associated with a client's specific requests (which would be tagged or keywords in a post's message).

Comment: What does on behalf of a client mean? You know you are not allowed to incentivize users for posting in any way?

Comment: Facebook actually has an API for public posts searching, but it is restricted to 'facebook partners', well, if are not one, better give up. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fort-pages-api